# Error on Android App

Tags: android

I got the error when I was creating a new activity on a button.

Here is my error log

> 03-22 22:27:53.425 21442-21442/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
>   03-22 22:27:53.425 21442-21442/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10265
>   03-22 22:27:53.425 21442-21442/? E/Zygote: v2
>   03-22 22:27:53.425 21442-21442/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
>   03-22 22:27:53.425 21442-21442/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SCH-R970_5.0.1_0016
>   03-22 22:27:53.425 21442-21442/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
>   My main.java

```
public class EntryDelish extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_entry_delish);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DcDesign.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });

}
```

}

My manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.cassieleong.delishcart">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".EntryDelish"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_entery_delish"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DcDesign"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any help appreciate.

Thanks.

Comment: try this     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DcDesign.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: you declared your DcDesign Activity inside manifest? i thing you miss it

Comment: It does not work still. - saeed

Comment: how can I declared it in the manifest

Comment: you declared your DcDesign Activity inside manifest? i thing you miss it .. you please check it

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".DcDesign"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             />

Comment: I have declared it in manifest. Please check my edited error log when I try to run. Thanks

Comment: startActivity(intent); use this

Comment: I still didnt get it right, getting the same error. Could it be because the DcDesign activity is link with ViewPager and Fragment?

Comment: app crashing while lounging?  which activity  you wish to want  first load?in your manifest file you declared DcDesign activty is the lounger activty ... if you want change your lounger Activty to EntryDelish  then you move intent filtter to EntryDelish  Activty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are incorrectly set lounger Activty  you Should add i`ntent-filter` to perticular Activity that you whish to want Loungh

**In your case**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".EntryDelish"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_entery_delish"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

           </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Actually I don't know What is the answer, ok, tell me? What is the difference between in question manifest and this answer manifest?

Answer (score 0):

"Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DcDesign.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);"

I thank this is no error,Commented the toolbar,then

Comment: Could it be because the DcDesign activity is link with ViewPager and Fragment?